# Вместо нужного значения в бд записывается array

Tags: php, mysql

Три часа сижу над простым кодом. В базу должно записаться мыло, которое вводили в форме а пишется Array.
Постом **email** отправляется **test@mail.ru**

```
 <? php
// extract session params
 ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
 ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
  session_start();
define('SID',session_id());

// data base connection params
$HOST = "localhost";
$LOGIN = "user";
$PASSWORD = "pass";
$DATA_BASE_NAME = "db";

mysql_connect($HOST,$LOGIN,$PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($DATA_BASE_NAME);

    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);

if (stristr($email, '@') == FALSE) {
    $status = "error";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'drop') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'set') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'update') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'create') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'insert') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, '1=1') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'table') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

   elseif(stristr($email, 'select') == TRUE) {
    $status = "inj";
}

else {
   $query = "UPDATE 'users' SET 'email' = '$email' WHERE 'login' = 'Admin'";
   mysql_query($query);
    $status = "sent";
}

mysql_close();
header ("Location: ../?page=profile&status=$status");

   ?>
```

Всё отправляется, всё доходит, **$status = "sent"** ТОЛЬКО вместо мыла в бд записывается **Array**

Comment: Тема сегодняшнего ток-шоу "SQL Injection и как он испортил мне нервы". Используй PDO и связку параметров с запросом. Дропы не пройдут 101%.

Comment: Посмотри свою форму, которой ты отправляешь данные. У тебя случаем поле не выглядит так? <input type="text" name="email[]" /> ? квадратные скобки делают скаляр массивом

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev, код то простой, только ТС походу только осваивается. Но как минимум ему надо знать на данном этапе, что:
1. переменные можно распечатывать через print_r() или var_dump()
2. Защита от SQL Injection построена совершенно неверно

Comment: > Возвращает указанную подстроку. Если подстрока needle не найдена, возвращается FALSE.

    elseif(stristr($email, 'drop') == TRUE) {

![](http://i.imgur.com/ZKKXYqws.jpg)

Оно, конечно, скастуется и сравнится (причем формально абсолютно так же, как и без `== TRUE`), но зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте, весьма вероятно в форме своей вы указали, как сказал Pavel `<input type="text" name="email[]" />`.
Чтобы решить проблему, необходимо проверить содержимое переменной, для этого напишите до:

$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
это:

var_dump($_POST["email"]);

Comment: не после, а до.
`var_dump($_POST["email"]);`

Comment: да Вы правы, исправлю

Comment: Я же сказал вход нормальный, name="email"

Comment: "Нормальный вход" - это подтверждено распечаткой значений, как здесь советовали? Предполагать-то можно что угодно.

Comment: ТС, вы можете сделать дамп переменной `$email` и выложить результ дампа сюда? Это сложно???